# return most common prefix in columns

Tags: r

If some columns in a data frame share a common prefix, how to I find out such common prefix?

**Note: prefix here means the longest substring before any number appears.**

data set may look like:

`Date,vix1,vix2,vix3,doSG124,doSG220`

In this case, I want to get `vix` instead of `doSG` because more columns (3) have `vix` as prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `table` and `which.max` after removing the 'suffix' part with `sub`.  Here, I assume that the suffix is the numeric part.

```
tbl <- table(sub('\\d+$', '', v1))
names(which.max(tbl))
#[1] "vix"
```

By using `sub`, we match the numeric part (`\\d+`) to the end of the string (`$`) and replace it with `''`

#### data

```
 v1 <- c('Date', 'vix1', 'vix2', 'vix3', 'doSG124', 'doSG220')
```

Comment: @W_ee added some explanation.  Do you have patterns other than the one you showed?